# jQuery Appending text from an input into a div when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There's a good chance that might be a repeat question, but I couldn't find an answer that seemed to resolve my problem. I'm trying to make a jQuery bit where text is inputted into a text box, a button is clicked, and the text in the text box gets appended to a div. The end product is to make a game, but for now I'm just trying to make sure that the variable gets stored and put into the div. Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Maybe a game maybe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Please enter your name.</h2>
    <form name="userInput">
        <input type="text" name="textInput"/>
    </form>
    <button id="confirm">Confirm</button>
    <br/>
    <div class="textOutput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS

```
h2 {
font-family:arial;
}
form {
display: inline-block;
}
.list {
font-family:garamond;
color:#cc0000;
}
```

And here's my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#confirm').click(function() {
        var playerName = $('input[name=textInput]').val();
        $(".textOutput").append("<p>" + playerName + "</p>");
    });
});
```

The idea is that text that gets inputted into the textInput box gets stored in the variable playerName. Then a `<p>` that contains playerName is appended to the .textOutput `<div>` when the confirm button is clicked. I'm using a Codecademy tutorial to help me confirm this. The code is almost exactly like the code in the tutorial. The only differences are the names of certain items, and the fact that the confirm button is a button and not a div. The code works perfectly fine in the tutorial, but when I try it in a normal editor, it doesn't work at all. I've even tried copying and pasting the exact code in the tutorial into my editor and still doesn't work. The editor I'm using is Sublime Text 2. I can't find what I'm missing here. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You are using JQuery, I ca't see you loading the JQuery library in your HTML

Answer (score 1):

Please replace

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then try you code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#confirm').click(function() {
       var playerName = $('input[name=textInput]').val();
       $(".textOutput").append("<p>" + playerName + "</p>");
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are saving it as text file.

You have to save the file as `.html` or `.htm` and wrap the script in `<script>` tag and wrap the css in `<style>` tag and then open it in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the jquery-library:
put e.g.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

inside the head-tag.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any jQuery libraries in the head tag.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Your code works, as shown here. http://jsfiddle.net/haxtbh/2gMgQ/